# Issues with with XYZ tiles and projections using QGIS for a fantasy map

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, xyz-tiles

So I should preface this that I'm a next to a complete beginner when it comes to QGIS and map science and all that. My knowledge is so limited that I don't even know what I don't know, and am basically clueless as to what sorts of questions I should be asking to get me pointed in the right direction as to what I want to do.

I've been working on a fantasy map for some time now, and have done quite a few iterations of it. I did previously do some work with Leaflet, and while I was able to get some of what I wanted, ultimately it didn't wind up serving my needs the way I wanted it to, so I decided to start from scratch with QGIS. As of now, I've made a map:

[image]

I made this map in Blender, and rendered out the XYZ tiles (around 21k of them, each 256px × 256px), and have them stored locally on my machine. My first issue though, is that this map is non-square, and I couldn't get that to work with QGIS. In fact, I couldn't get it to work with Leaflet either. My workaround was to squish the map to a square in Blender, and then render out XYZ tiles from that.

Am I going about this in the right way? Or is there a way to go about using XYZ tiles with a non-square image that's 2:1 instead of 1:1 while still using 256px × 256px tiles?  Or should I be rendering out non-square tiles as well, say 256px × 128px?

Next, when working in QGIS, I did some poking around, and I think, but am not sure, that I would be able to get that 2:1 ratio image with using a different projection. I tried a few, but ones like World Patterson (ESRI:54079) that give me a look close to what I want don't seem to work the way I want them to. For some reason that I can't figure out, the map stretches and squishes whenever I pan around. When I click Zoom Full, it looks how I want it to. However, moving the map vertically after a certain point causes everything near the equator to stretch vertically, and stuff near the poles to squash down. I have a suspicion that this is intended behavior, but again, I don't know enough to know what I don't know.

For now, the one projection I've been able to get working close to what I want is World Times (ESRI:54048), but it's not really where I want things to be as there's too much distortion:

[image]

Is there a way to get the view that I want, with the width being twice that of the height? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Essentially, my end goal here is to have that 2:1 map where I can then add different states, locations, road networks, etc...  I intend to use this map mostly for my own reference in world-building, as I have a lot of different projects that take place in this setting, such as comics, short stories, tabletop games, etc...  It is extremely useful to be able to plot out the different locations on a map and then to use that map to calculate the distances between places which allows me to figure out travel times.  It also lets me calculate the area of certain states, which I can then use to calculate populations.  Therefore, there's a lot of the more in-depth GIS stuff that I don't quite need beyond the basics, I think.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, so Questions with enumerated question lists are likely to be closed. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on your most pressing issue.

Comment: Just write "How to use my custom map tiles in QGIS" as *the question* somewhere at the end to appeal to the overzealous counter of question marks. To me the question is perfectly clear and your "questionmarked" thoughts are helpful.

Comment: You have multiple zoomlevels with different content, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  I have it set up in Blender to use a different material and level of detail at each zoom level, allowing for better resolution and more features the deeper I zoom.

Comment: Any chance you can share the image files, 2-3 of the smallest zoomlevels by directory size should be enough? I would like to go via VRT to a GeoTIFF with overviews, that should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

There are various options, depending on which things are important to you.

My suggestion would be to just georeference the raw image file, and let QGIS handle everything from there. To do that, you can:

- calculate control points
- add control points using gdal_translate
- load into QGIS

Once it's in QGIS, you can use QGIS tools to edit, you can export out XYZ tiles, etc.

I've done all of the steps below on the image file from the question, and get a satisfactory result in QGIS.

**Calculate Control Points**

This is probably the hardest part of the exercise. That said, it's just a case of mapping pixels to lat/lon using interpolation. The x pixels need to be mapped from -180 to +180. The y pixels you have a bit of flexibility, but the maximum latitude should be 85.0511 if you want to align with Web Mercator. You could probably use less (say from -80 to +80). Really depends on the importance of your polar areas.

I experimented with using dozens of control points, but I got the same result with just 9. This was using your 4096 x 2048 image from the question. If your original raw image has more pixels, you'd need to adjust the control points accordingly.

If you need to create control points, the formula for:

- longitude is `(max_x/2 - x)/max_x * 360`
- latitude is `(max_y/2 - y)/max_y * 2 * max_lat` where max_lat is 85.0511, or whatever smaller value you choose. I created these in Excel.

**Add Control Points**

If you're running Windows, fire up the OSGEO4W Shell, and run the following, replacing filenames (and control points?) accordingly:

```
gdal_translate ^
-gcp 1 1 179.912109375 84.9680422851563 -gcp 2048 1 0 84.9680422851563 -gcp 4096 1 -180 84.9680422851563 ^
-gcp 1 1024 179.912109375 0 -gcp 2048 1024 0 0 -gcp 4096 1024 -180 0 ^
-gcp 1 2048 179.912109375 -85.0511 -gcp 2048 2048 0 -85.0511 -gcp 4096 2048 -180 -85.0511 ^
C:\temp\FwIVzoM.jpeg C:\temp\FwIVzoM.tif
```

At this point, you could warp the image using gdalwarp, but you'll end up with an image that's no longer 2:1, and for your purposes, it's unlikely to make much difference.

**Load into QGIS**

Just drag and drop, and set whichever CRS you like.

This is using CRS EPSG:4326 (WGS84). For comparison, I have overlaid a map of the world from OpenStreetMap, which lines up almost exactly.

Keep in mind that if you are using an Earth-based projection, distances & areas are going to approximate the real world.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this with tiles?  Because while I can see this working for what I need, I'm not sure if it will allow me the level of detail I want.  That's because with tiles, I can render out 21k tiles at 256 x 256 pixels, it just takes a long time.  But to get to zoom level 7 I don't think my machine has the ability to render an image that's 65k x 32k pixels, it would just flat out crash attempting to render something that size.

Comment: Not sure you can georeference an XYZ tileset (but I could be wrong). However you could take the georeferencing approach a step further - by say exporting out 128 tiles of say 4096 x 4096 (or whatever makes sense). You'd have to calculate control points for each tile. The calculations would be a little tricky to work out, but the approach would be similar to the formulas above, with an extra piece of logic for where the tile is in the array. Once you've done it once, you would be set. Finally, you could build the tiles back into a VRT, which QGIS should be able to handle.

Comment: Hmm, doing it tile by tile might be a bit difficult, as once everything is rendered it's likely that there are going to be over 300k tiles.  Or is there a way to automate that?

Comment: I suggest exporting out tiles at 4096x4096 (which would be 128 tiles from a 65kx32k image) and georeferencing these. This could be scripted once, and then automated.

Comment: You might need to elaborate further on what you are planning on using the various applications (Blender/QGIS/Leaflet) for. I'm familiar with QGIS & Leaflet - less so with Blender.